# jqGrid - multiple rows in a single record

Tags: jqgrid

I want to add paging to a grid where multiple rows count as one record.

Is this doable ? Maybe if I could access the inner workings of the pager ?
Basically 3 rows should count as 1 record.

Any ideas on how I could do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want 3 rows to count as 1 record just multiple the rowNum property to be 3 times what its supposed to be.  So, if you want the grid to have 10 records and 3 rows per record, make rowNum be 30.